# How to hide waffle icon, office 365, SharePoint link inside Search on SP Online teamsite?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, team-sites

Hello I would like to know what is best way to hide waffle icon, office 365 link and sharepoint link inside search on team-site.
[image]

Comment: Tip - don't hide. Learn to live with it and educate end-users. You can use CSS selectors to set property display:none , but since this is SPO, the selectors are most likely to be changed after some time and your users will come back to you again about this.

Comment: @GautamSheth  how do I do it

Comment: I have to agree, what is the point of hiding the waffle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be different in your tenant, hence please check the selectors

I have used the below css to hide the waffle icon and the text :

```
<style>
.o365cs-nav-header16 .o365cs-nav-brandingText, #O365_MainLink_NavMenu{
display:none;
}
</style>
```

Add it inside a script editor webpart/content editor webpart or masterpage of site collection.

Create a css file and the above line of code. After that add to the site collection as below:

If your site is publishing site follow the mentioned steps below:

Go to Site Settings > Look and Feel > Design Manager > Publish and Apply design > Specify the path of CSS
[image]

Comment: I can't edit search page.

Comment: have updated answer, please check

Comment: I have done it before. However when i search on teamsite and load it up search page then office 365 shows up.

Comment: Press F12 in browser console and check the selector. At my end its as below:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fesx3.png , change the css accordingly

Comment: it same as yours

Comment: can you try `display:none !important;` and check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58579/discussion-between-user3161390-and-gautam-sheth).